# error in starting and connecting to neo4j from py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to connect to neo4j from py2neo:

```
    from py2neo.server import GraphServer
    server=GraphServer()
    server.start()
```

At this stage when I check the logs I see that the server is up and running:

```
    2016-06-10 09:41:09.928-0600 INFO  Initiating metrics..
    2016-06-10 09:42:01.288-0600 INFO  Successfully started database
    2016-06-10 09:42:01.305-0600 INFO  Starting HTTP on port 7474 (40 threads available)
   2016-06-10 09:42:01.428-0600 INFO  Mounted REST API at: /db/manage
   2016-06-10 09:42:01.472-0600 INFO  Mounting static content at /webadmin
   2016-06-10 09:42:01.509-0600 INFO  Mounting static content at /browser
  2016-06-10 09:42:03.085-0600 INFO  Remote interface ready and available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/
```

But in ipython I get the below error:

```
       TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call  last)
<ipython-input-46-5e4be8f41f99> in <module>()
 ----> 1 server.start()

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/server.pyc in start(self)
190             uri = None
191             kwargs = {}
--> 192             for line in out.decode("utf-8").splitlines(keepends=False):
193                 if line.startswith("Using additional JVM arguments:"):
194                     kwargs["jvm_arguments"] = shlex.split(line[32:])

 TypeError: splitlines() takes no keyword arguments
```

If any more info is needed please feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Most likely there's a mismatch between the Python versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around I have been starting Neo4j from linux itself using./bin/neo4j start and it remains started even when I log off from linux.

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of Python, Neo4j and py2neo are you using? Are they listed as supported versions on py2neo.org?

Comment: How do I find out version of py2neo being used?Python 2.7 and Neo4j enterprise 2.3.1..